# Objective-C: Why am I getting a compile error when importing a header file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm curious what some reasons might be as to getting a compiler error for simply importing a header file. If I comment it out, everything compiles just fine -- the header/implementation for the class I'm trying to import into one of my UIViewController's get passed the compiler without any warnings. However, as soon as I include it, I get a multitude of errors.

I'm trying to use Apple's Reachability app in my own code, and by doing something like:

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

I get a ton of:

```
error: syntax error before 'target'
error: syntax error before 'SCNetworkReachabilityFlags'
error: syntax error before 'SCNetworkReachabilityRef'
error: syntax error before 'SCNetworkReachabilityRef'
fatal error: method definition not in @implementation context
```

It's mostly complaining regarding:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target,       SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags, void *info);
- (BOOL)isNetworkAvailableFlags:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags *)outFlags;
- (SCNetworkReachabilityRef)reachabilityRefForHostName:(NSString *)hostName;
- (CFRunLoopRef)startListeningForReachabilityChanges:(SCNetworkReachabilityRef)reachability onRunLoop:(CFRunLoopRef)runLoop;
```

Any idea why this is only happening when I try to import the header file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you probably need to

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

That error is almost always caused by the non-definition of the word preceding the error word (in this case, `SCNetworkReachabilityRef` preceding `target`).

Hence you have not defined `SCNetworkReachabilityRef` and (it looks like) all the other `"SC..."` types as well.

I'm not sure that `SystemConfiguration.h` *is* included in `Reachability.h` (if you're using the sample code from [here](http://iphone.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/Classes/Reachability.m)).

That code includes both `SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h` *and* `Reachability.h`.

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, the 1.5 version of Apple's Reachability includes the

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

but you need to import the SystemConfiguration framework in your app. You can get it there /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework